# object categorie is null when I select Details for a Category

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am running a MVC WebStore.  I come in an it display all the categories perfectly.  When I tried to select the details of 1 category it gave me an httpNotFound.   It seems my id is not pickup for an unknown reason.
I don't understand how this id is populated.  Thanks for your help

Here is my HomeController.cs

```
 namespace MVCWebStore.Controllers
 {
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
         private MVCWebStoreDdEntities1 db = new MVCWebStoreDdEntities1();

         //
         // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Categories.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)    <== error here the id is set to 0
        {
            Categorie categorie = db.Categories.Find(id);
            if (categorie == null)       <== categorie is null
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(categorie);
        }
```

Here is the Details.cshtml

```
 @model MVCWebStore.Models.Categorie

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Details";
 }

 <h2>Details</h2>

 <fieldset>
     <legend>Categorie</legend>

     <div class="display-label">
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdCategorie)
     </div>
     <div class="display-field">
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IdCategorie)
     </div>

     <div class="display-label">
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomCategorie)
     </div>
     <div class="display-field">
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NomCategorie)
     </div>
 </fieldset>
 <p>


@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

Here is the Index.cshtml

```
 @model IEnumerable<MVCWebStore.Models.Categorie>

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

 <h2>Index</h2>

 <p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
 </p>
 <table>
     <tr>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomCategorie)
         </th>
         <th></th>
     </tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
     <tr>

         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomCategorie)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
             @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
             @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
         </td>
     </tr>
 }

 </table>
```

Comment: how does your Listing view/action looks like ? can you share code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Home Controller, you set the default value of `int id` to 0. That means when you don't have any category with an id of 0, an `HttpNotFound` page is returned - this is why your customized id is not being picked up.

To fix this, you can change the Details ActionResult to something like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Categorie categorie = db.Categories.Find(id);
    if (categorie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(categorie);
}
```

In your Index.cshtml:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", { id=item.ID }) //make sure that in your database, the Category table has a column called "ID"
```

Comment: I tried your code. I got the same result. The id is null.  I was expecting the Id will have the id of the selected row (where I choose Details option).  Why it is not picking up the Id of the chosen row ?  Thanks for your help

Comment: does I need to put something here in the Details.cshtml for the commented code ,new {  ...}   ?          @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |

Comment: Could you please show me how you create a link to a Details page in your Index.cshtml? It might look like this:

@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", { id=item.ID })

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |  I am pretty sure I am missing the key in parameter here... right ?

Comment: You can if you want, but that's a link to an Edit page. It shouldn't affect any Details page.

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ })

Comment: Yes, that looks like it, the portion that is commented out is where you pass the ID. So just uncomment it (in your Index.cshtml):

@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.PrimaryKey })

Comment: Why this is comment out?  I am asking to generate it automatically and the system is putting comments ?  this is strange I find.  Thanks for your help again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48512/discussion-between-quinn-and-user3127986)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are passing the id. Looks like you have it commented out. Try this.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details","Home", new { id=item.PrimaryKey },null)
```

This will create an anchor tag like this (4 will be replaced with the primary key of your item.

```
<a href="/Home/Details/4">Details</a>
```